# JPA с Enum в БД влияние на перформанс

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

К сожалению есть только два `EnumType` `STRING` и `ORDINAL`. При использовании `ORDINAL` есть опасность что в большом проекте его поменяют или удалят значение и соответственно все сломается. Хотелось бы иметь третий тип типа `NUMBER` в котором мы бы создавали `Enum`s и передавали бы номер который должен был бы испльзовался для значения записи в БД. К примеру

```
public enum AnyType {
    TREE(0), // ну или TREE(0, значения которые нужны для конструктора
    CAR(1);
   private final int number;
   private final int age;
   
   AnyType(int number, int age) {
       this.number = number;
       this.age = age;
    }
```

и чтобы `JPA` использовал `getNumber` как значение которое бы использовалось как `ORDINAL` но уже меньше шансов на то что может что то сломаться при изменении `Enum`. Как можно такое реализовать или как можно используя `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` улучшить производительность при выборке и записи данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте свою реализацию `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter` для типа `AnyType`.

Она должна конвертировать `AnyType` в число и обратно используя свойство `number` в `AnyType`. Потом назначьте этот конвертор на соответствующие поля либо глобально с помощью `@Converter(autoApply = true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так?

```
public enum AnyType {
    TREE(0), // ну или TREE(0, значения которые нужны для конструктора
    CAR(1);
   private final int number;
   private int age=0;
   
    AnyType(int number) {
       this.number = number;
       this.age = number;
    }
    
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Тогда  `AnyType.TREE.getAge()` - будет гарантированно совпадать с вашим ordinal и в то же время не будет выдавать `TREE` в БД.